# Heroku is not responding

Tags: node.js, heroku

Today `Heroku` servers do not seem to respond to anything I tried.
The usual URLs https://www.heroku.com or https://www.heroku.com/platform do not display anything in the browser.

By the same token https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ does not respond either.

Is there anything to do?

Comment: For me this question is not related to programming, but more for issues. I think that the best thing you can do is to wait until Heroku will respond again.

Comment: True, this is not a programming issue. This is an issue a programmer can face, within the course of his/her work task.

Comment: I understand you.

Comment: After a few hours, it came back.

Comment: I knew it will come back, that's what **always** happening with servers. The servers were temporarily shut down, but now they are running.